# Java implementation of Google Custom Search API

Tags: java, google-api, google-search, google-custom-search

I need some help using the `Google API` in Java. Basically, I need to create a web application in Java that will call the `Google Custom Search Engine` (using their API) and retrieve the result.

I have read the Google starting guide, but not sure how to use their API. Can anyone please point me towards some examples or tutorial links.

Answer (score 4):

The [download](http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/com/google/apis/google-api-services-customsearch/v1-rev2-1.5.0-beta/google-api-services-customsearch-v1-rev2-1.5.0-beta.zip) off http://google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/ has all the libraries you'll need, but the [samples](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples) doesn't have anything specific to Custom Search. The closest you'll get is [here](http://blog.lux-medien.com/2011/08/google-custom-search-java-implementation/): they provide a [jar file with source code](http://www.lux-medien.com/googlux-customsearch-alpha-0.1.1.jar). It doesn't use the Google Java client library, but might get you started with the [REST api](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest).